# Auditing application users activity in web application in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Our Web application is hosted in a public server through IIS. Our requirement is we need to audit the application user's activities.

We have a SQL database ,All the users details will be in User table .When these users logging into the application, the connection will established through common SQL login called sql_user for all the users to the database.So we need to monitor what are the records are shown by the particular user for security purpose.

I tried the SQL server Auditing but it only show the common sql_user as User for all the application users.

Comment: Could you clarify this point :So we need to monitor what are the records are shown by the particular user for security purpose.

Comment: is there any way you differentiate users

Comment: Yes. For Example: user A login and see the patient's records in application by search in a module. User B logins and see another patient's records .So we need a track to what are the records are seen by the different user.